# Windows 10 - Remote Desktop Connection issue ONLY TO/FROM specific computer

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I have 3 PCs in my home network, all 3 with Windows 10: A, B, and C.

From A, I can remote (`mstsc`) to B.
From B, I can remote to C.
From A, I can remote to B, and from within that remote session, I can connect from B to C.
But **I cannot connect from A to C**. I get this generic error message: [image]

Other info:

- yes, I can `ping` from A to C
- the user on B and C is the same (an online Microsoft account, *smth@outlook...*)
- both B and C have checked "Only allow connections from computers running remote desktop with network level authentication..."

Does anybody know what possible causes could there be?
I'm very confused, don't even know how to start investigating this... :)

Comment: Just for the sake of testing this.. can you check if it works when you uncheck on C "Only allow connections from computers running Remote Desktop with Network Level Authentication (Recommended)." You can jump to this setting by searching "allow remote" in your start menu

Comment: both B and C have that option checked.  
I tried unchecking it on C, it did not help.

Comment: On C, log out of your Microsoft account and then log back in using the password.  Then try again.  This may be a weird MS account caching issue that gets encountered from time to time when an account  password was changed but  you haven't been explicitly forced to re-enter it on C.  B might not be affected because the common user account.  A tries to login to C with valid credentials but C needs a kick in the *** to accept them. Especially if you typically use the pin or fingerprint reader to login to C (on C) rather than the pwd.

Comment: Is there any interconnecting hardware that could be causing the problem such as switches or additional routers... extenders and the like? A good way to rule this out would be to make sure computers A, B and C are all connected to the same access point, even if temporarily you attempted to do this wirelessly. It would at least help rule out any computer based settings being the cause.